# How to undo bundle install --deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, bundle

I have been working on a rails app and been deploying regularly to heroku using local git depository. I accidentally ran the command:

```
bundle install --deployment
```

It seems it downloaded all the gems to the local folder, and now when I want to upload to heroku it is trying to upload many megabytes of gems... How do I undo the command I ran and delete the local gems? How do I prevent bundle install from downloading all gems again?

Comment: How were the gems uploaded to heroku? You added them to git?

Comment: Yes I usually do git add . for the sake of simplicity ( i know it's probably not the best practice)

Comment: Go back to last ok git commit, the one before running `bundle install --deployment`.

Answer (score 8):

Wanted to make this an answer because it was jrochkind comment that helped

```
rm -rf vendor/bundle
```

The f in -rf ignores the questions asking if you want to really remove this file.

```
bundle install --no-deployment
```

The above will disable bundle deployment mode and install needed packages in a non production enviroment

```
git add .
git commit -m "fixed deployment bundle"
git push heroku master
```

The above will add all your lock file to git, create a commit with the new update.  It will then send your fixed lock file to your master branch to Heroku master branch (It only has a master) along with any other changes you have done.

If you need to send a different branch to Heroku other than your master then instead of `git push heroku master` run the following code:

```
git push heroku development:master
```

The above command will push your development branch to the Heroku master branch.  change `development` to the branch name you want to send to Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Edit Bundler config file at your app root path .bundle/config and remove following line:

```
BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT: "true"
```

Or with oneliner:

```
sed '/BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT: "true"/d' .bundle/config
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

First, remove all your local gems.

```
rm -r vendor/bundle
```

Bundle again

```
bundle install
```

Run `git add --all`

Commit and push again to heroku.

Comment: What folder are the local gems? Shouldn't something follow "rm" to specify which files/folders to remove?

Comment: I think when you bundle again with `bundle install`, it will "remember" your previous `--deployment` choice.  You have to undo it with `bundle install --no-deployment`. I think?